# problem in detecting logoff using c#

Tags: c#

I tried to detect logoff event and write it in a text.

How can this be fixed? i wanted to write the logoff time in a text file but the text file is not created when i logoff the PC.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
    Console.ReadLine();
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch -= SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
}
static void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogoff)
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("D:\\date.txt");
        tw.WriteLine("logoff" + DateTime.Now);
        tw.Close();
    }
    if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogon)
    {
        TextWriter tw1 = new StreamWriter("D:\\date.txt");
        tw1.WriteLine("logoff" + DateTime.Now);
        tw1.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we tell your how to fix it if you haven't told us what the problem is? Edit your question to include those details.

Comment: I am guessing that you have just subscribed to the event. But who is raising the event?

Comment: I don't think you can detect logoff from a console application, which is what you appear to be writing. By the time the logoff occurs, all code running within that logon session will have ended - including this console application.

Comment: @Damien what if i make this a windows service. will it work??

Comment: @ZapSwami - a windows service is better placed to monitor such events, since it continues running no matter who, or how many, users have active sessions. as to "will it work", I don't know, since I assume the above code was just to experiment with this event, rather than whatever you're trying to actually achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work unless the app has a facility for reading Windows messages which your console application doesn't have. According to the documentation for [SystemEvents.SessionSwitch Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> This event is only raised if the message pump is running. In a Windows
>   service, unless a hidden form is used or the message pump has been
>   started manually, this event will not be raised. For a code example
>   that shows how to handle system events by using a hidden form in a
>   Windows service, see the SystemEvents class.

If you insist on running this as a console app, check [Handling Messages in Console Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163417.aspx) which is a tutorial for running the message pump inside a console application.